# Correct connection string for external database via IP

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm trying to connect with an external database with my project.
Since now on localDB I did use a connection string like

```
 connectStr = 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=Someserver;Database=SOmeDB;Uid=MyUser;Pwd=HardPassword;Trusted_Connection=no;';
```

Now I need to get into a external database but I keep getting connection errors like.

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

My sample connection for external database

```
connectStr ='Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=111.111.111.111,1439;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=SOmeDB;User ID=MyUser;Password=HardPassword;Trusted_Connection=no;';
```

Any tips here? What might be wrong?

Comment: Can you connect the instance from the host using a different tool; such as SSMS, ADS or `sqlcmd`? If not, I would suggest the problem is network based. If you *can* then check the logs on the SQL Server instance, as the true authentication error will be in there.

Comment: If you use .NET, why use OLEDB instead of SqlClient? Why hard-code the network library and default port?

Comment: @Larnu I tried to login with SSMS giving the server name as 1111.111.111.111:1439 <- this port was opened for me and windows authentication. Tried both from company IP and my hotspot and I couln't connect.

PanagiotisKanavos it just code inherited from my senior in a MS ERP App. If it works don't touch it... But now the specs changed.

Comment: Tip: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes I did see this site. THere is where I found something familar that don't actually work for me.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/connect-via-an-ip-address/

Comment: In your question, you have a comma before the portnumber (",1439"). A typo in the post?

Comment: Are you sure port that `1439` was opened for you? The port for the default `MSSQLSERVER` instance is normally `1433`.

Comment: I asked our Administrator for a way to connect into this server so I could execute a SQL Query using Openrowset commands because I need files stored there. He gave me the IP and said he openned this port for me. Using 1433 port gives the same errors
@HansKeﬆing it's not a typo I belive, connections strings using port look like this

Comment: "Openrowset" requires a linked server - something you did not previously mention and something that contradicts your original question. At this point the context of your question is not clear - whether this occurs when trying to connect in openrowset (which is done within your connected database server instance via tsql) or when trying to connect via your application. Regardless, MS has a [connection troubleshooter here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/topic/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server-ae23c94b-b64b-5056-8b62-22e1694bb889?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).